Azure AD B2C localization string IDs for APIs
I'm working on localization in Azure AD B2C custom workflows and I'm struggling to identify the stringIDs to use for customizing messages displayed to users.
In general I would like to find a way to identify all the elementIDs and stringIDs available for the provided Microsof APIs like

api.selfasserted
api.selfasserted.totp
api.localaccountpasswordreset
api.signuporsignin
...

I'm already aware of MS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids but it clearly looks incomplete specially on error messages like the ones displayed in TOTP verification page or selfasserted pages.
For instance UserMessageIfIncorrectOTPCodeEntered is used to display a message when TOTP entered is incorrect.
But I didn't found he stringID used when the user enters an incomplete verification (this message is displayed as soon as the user starts typing the code "Enter the 6-digit verification code generated by the the Authenticator app in the box") it might be something like UserMessageIf....
Or the stringID when the user enters a valid verification code but after he verification session has expired "The specified verification session is invalid or may have expired"

One thing I've done in the past is look at the Javascript that gets generated on the page. It'll have a global variable called CONTENT (which you can also print out in the console) that contains the translations used on that page. This might not answer your question of a more complete documentation, but it might help :)
